# On the relatinoship between matrix inequalities and matrix norms.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the usual definition of a norm of a matrix and inequality between matrices:

Given a generic $n \times n$ matrix $A$ we define $||A|| = \max_{||x|| = 1} ||Ax||$.

Given two symmetric $n \times n$  matrices $A,B$ with the notation  $A>B$ we mean  $A - B$ is positive definite.

Is it then true that $|| A || < m \iff -I m < A < I m$ ?
where $m$ is a real number greater than zero and $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

Or, more generally, do these two definitions play with each other like the definition of the absolute value and the definition of inequalities between real numbers?

Comment: Note that using `\|` instead of `||` for the norm bars will result in better formatting

Comment: Your inequality holds for symmetric matrices $A$ but not for "a generic $n \times n$ matrix $A$".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Well, for a generic $A$, the positive-definite partial order isn't really defined...

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks for the comments, I appreciate them greatly. Yes I am talking about symmetric matrices, maybe I should make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Let's look at $\|A\mathbf x\|$ first. For symmetric matrices, $\|A\mathbf x\|^2 = \mathbf x^{\mathsf T}\!A^2 \mathbf x$.

We can write $\mathbf x$ in the unit eigenbasis $\mathbf v^{(1)}, \dots, \mathbf v^{(n)}$ of $A$: $\mathbf x = x_1 \mathbf v^{(1)} + \dots + x_n \mathbf v^{(n)}$. Here, since $\|\mathbf x\| = 1$, we have $x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2 = 1$. Note that if $\mathbf v$ is a unit eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $\mathbf v^{\mathsf T}\!A^2\mathbf v = \lambda^2$.

Then $\mathbf x^{\mathsf T}\!A^2\mathbf x = x_1^2 \lambda_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2 \lambda_n^2$, which is a convex combination of $\lambda_1^2, \dots, \lambda_n^2$. If $\lambda_1 < \dots < \lambda_n$, then $\mathbf x^{\mathsf T}\!A^2\mathbf x$ is maximized either at $\lambda_1^2$ (by setting $\mathbf x = \mathbf v^{(1)}$ or at $\lambda_n^2$ (by setting $\mathbf x = \mathbf v^{(n)}$). And so $\|A\| = \max_i \{|\lambda_i|\}$.

(This is true for symmetric $A$ only; for general $A$, $\|A\|$ is more closely related to the singular values of $A$.)

Meanwhile, $-mI \prec A \prec mI$ is equivalent to saying that all the eigenvalues of $A$ are strictly between $-m$ and $m$:

- we have $-mI \prec A$ iff $A + mI \succ 0$ iff $A+mI$ is positive definite, which means all eigenvalues of $A+mI$ are positive, and $A$ can't have eigenvalues less than or equal to $-m$.
- we have $A \prec mI$ if $mI - A \succ 0$ iff $mI-A$ is positive definite, which means all eigenvalues of $mI-A$ are positive, and $A$ can't have eigenvalues greater than or equal to $m$.

Therefore $-mI \prec A \prec mI$ is exactly equivalent to $\|A\| < m$, provided $A$ is symmetric.